# PHP Session Lost

Tags: php, session, authentication, mysqli

I know there is a lot of questions out there but they dont give much info or use other methods to authenticate. Lets begin:

I have a login page and main page.
I login saving session in $_SESSION
In every page i make session_start() and then i check if the user is loged looking $_SESSION.

When i login it redirects me to the main page. 
When i try login.php it detects correctly im in and redirects to main.php.
When i refresh main.php it detects correctly my session.

THEN, i want to make a change in DB so i use the jquery function $.post to send post data to action.php and do some staff.
Action.php echo "true" so the $.post handler can detect the change has been made correctly and redirect.
Action.php echo "false" so the $.post handler alert an error was ocured.

**When i make that change to the DB, it gets done and echo true so main.php refresh itself showing the change BUT INSTEAD OF REFRESH IT COME BACK TO LOGIN.PHP LOSING ALL SESSION DATA.**

Here some code:

**start_session**

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    //session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"],              $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_set_cookie_params(7200, "/", $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
    }
```

**top of main.php and login.php and action.php**

```
include('../db_connect.php');
include('../functions.php');

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a php session. 

if(!login_check($mysqli)){
    header('Location: ../');
}
```

**Javascript function to post data to action.php**

```
function createTeam(){

    var serializedData = $('#new_team_form').serialize();

    $.post('action.php', serializedData , function (resp) {
        if(resp == "false"){
            $('#exists').html("El grupo que intentas crear ya existe o ha habido un error en la petición.");
        }else{
            window.location ="./";
        }
    });
    return false; //Needs to return false cause its the submit button of form
}
```

**action.php - what is echoed will be the return for $.post()**

```
<?php

include '../db_connect.php';
include '../functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a php session. 


$team = $_POST['team'];
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;



if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM teams WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1")) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $team); // Bind "$user_id" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();


        if($stmt->num_rows == 1) { 
            echo "false1".$team;
        } else {
            //Creamos el grupo en la base de datos y ponemos al usuario en dicho grupo

            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO teams (id, name) VALUES (DEFAULT, '$team')")) { 
                $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
                if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE  members SET  team =  '".$team."' WHERE  members.id ='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1 ")) {
                    $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
                    echo "true";
                }else{
                    echo "false2";
                }

            }else{
                echo "false3";
            }
        }
     } else {
        echo "false4";
     }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your code and issue you have asked... Through main.php there are no session transfer to action.php, except that all things are running correctly ..

Use this syntax...

//**The session retrieve the values in form of :**

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

**//And its shifted to the another page where the session is retrieved :**

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

**I think in your action.php the session is not properly declares in retrieval form. Write this in action.php**

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

Comment: I dont understand well your answer but I think you are trying to say that: $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id must be rewritten as $user_ide = $_SESSION['user_id']. What a stupid mistake, all goes well now, thanks

Comment: Sorry.. for my answer to be not in well explained form But its means to be same as you mention above in a comment there is to be a syntax error.. So At last your problem is to be solve out...that is to be my pleasure..